# How to call parent class objects within a subclass?

Tags: java

I'm not sure if I'm asking this right, as I'm attempting to teach myself Java.  I have a class which contains my main method, and within this class are several subclasses that need access to my user settings using java.util.Properties.  I have to create the properties object in every subclass in order to make it work, and I can't reference the object using configFilePath, it must be null.  I'm wondering if I can create this public object within the parent class, so I don't need to create it in all of its subclasses?  Here is my code, I'm really not sure I'm doing this right although it works.

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
    Settings config = new Settings(); //this is the object I want to reference within subclasses

    class Update extends SwingWorker<Integer, Void> {  //first subclass

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Settings config = new Settings(configFilePath);  //yet I have to create the object within every subclass, this time an argument is required.  
            String templateDir = config.getProperty("templatedir");
            String writePath = config.getProperty("outputdir");
            //do some logic code, not required for my question
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            Update2 update2 = new Update2();
            update2.execute(); //start the next subclass which also needs access to Settings(configFilePath)
        }
    } 
}

public class Settings extends JFrame {
    String configFilePath = "C:/path/to/settings.properties";
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    public Settings(String configFilePath) throws IOException {

        this.configFilePath = configFilePath;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(configFilePath);
            properties.load(fis);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            setDefaults();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right or not, it seems to work but seems to be rather redundant having to create the config object every time I need to access my user settings.  I hope this hasn't been asked before, and if it has please link me, as I could not find it.

Comment: Why does your `Settings` class extend `JFrame`?  I think you need to do some research on what `extends` and inheritance in general does.

Comment: Because it's a new dialog that interacts with the user in order to obtain user settings.  This isn't my entire code, this is just the code relevant to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the Setting class as a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern, here is one example:

```
public class Settings extends JFrame{
    String configFilePath = "C:/path/to/settings.properties";
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    private static Settings instance;

    public static Settings getInstance(){
       if(instance==null){
           instance = new Setting();
       }
       return instance;
    }

    private Settings() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(configFilePath);
            properties.load(fis);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            setDefaults();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in any other class of your system:

```
Settings.getInstance().getProperty("...");
```

Comment: Thank you, this saves me a lot of keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

From `Update` you can use `Frame1.this` to access the `this` of `Frame1` (because `Update` is an inner class of `Frame1`).

Then to access `config` you can use `Frame1.this.config`.

Here is a working example:

```
public class PrefixerFactory {
    private String prefix; // Used by Prefixer

    public PrefixerFactory(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public Prefixer createPrefixer() {
        return new Prefixer();
    }

    public class Prefixer { // Inner class
        public String addPrefix(String value) {
            // Using "prefix" from PrefixerFactory
            return PrefixerFactory.this.prefix + value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prefixer helloPrefixer = new PrefixerFactory("Hello ").createPrefixer();
        Prefixer goodbyePrefixer = new PrefixerFactory("Good bye ").createPrefixer();

        System.out.println(helloPrefixer.addPrefix("world")); // Hello world
        System.out.println(goodbyePrefixer.addPrefix("world")); // Good bye world
    }
}
```